Wavefunctional of Abelian Chern-Simons theory
In section II.B of this paper, Topologically massive gauge theories, they carried out canonical quantization of the Abelian Chern-Simons theory in the $A_0=0$ gauge. The Gauss law was then imposed as a constraint on the space of states. In the Schr$\ddot{\textrm{o}}$dinger representation, the energy eigenstates $\Psi(\textbf{A})$ satisfy (eq. 2.28a in the paper)
$$\frac{1}{2}\int d\textbf{r}\bigg[\bigg(\frac{1}{i}\frac{\delta}{\delta A^i(\textbf{r})}-\frac{\mu}{2}\epsilon^{ij}A^j(\textbf{r})\bigg)^2+B(\textbf{r})^2\bigg]
\Psi(\textbf{A})=E\Psi(\textbf{A}),\tag{2.28a}$$
where $B$ is the magnetic field. The Gauss law then has the following form (eq.2.28b)
$$\bigg[\frac{1}{i}\partial_i\frac{\delta}{\delta A^i(\textbf{r})}+\frac{\mu}{2}B(\textbf{r})\bigg]\Psi(\textbf{A})=0.\tag{2.28b}$$
Then they claimed that the ground state is given by
$$\Psi_0(\textbf{A})=e^{i\chi(\textbf{A})}\textrm{exp}\bigg(-\frac{1}{2}\int d\textbf{r}\,d\textbf{r}^{'}\, A^i(\textbf{r})K^{ij}(\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}^{'})A^j(\textbf{r}^{'})\bigg),$$
$$\chi(\textbf{A})=\frac{\mu}{2}\int d\textbf{r}\, B\,\boldsymbol{\nabla}^{-1}\cdot\textbf{A},$$
$$K^{ij}(\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}^{'})=\int\frac{d\textbf{k}}{(2\pi)^2}e^{-i\textbf{k}\cdot(\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}^{'})}(\delta^{ij}-\hat{k}^i\hat{k}^j)\sqrt{\mu^2+\mathbf{k}^2},$$
$$\boldsymbol{\nabla}^{-1}=\frac{\boldsymbol{\nabla}}{\nabla^2}.$$
I am stucked in deriving the lowest energy solution. Any tip or help is appreciated.
